# unable to fetch availablity from PSS

Tags: sabre

We need to request OTA_AirAvailLLSRQ from our microservice via USG and liberty to fetch availability.(we will pass ATH token as well along with request). please guid me code flow.

Answer (score 0):

Good day, Prashat.
I hope everything is going well for you.

Perhaps the Sabre team's postman collection on GitHub will help you find what you're looking for.
The link is on below line

https://github.com/SabreDevStudio/postman-collections

Best regards.